# iOS8 lines drawn with coreGraphics fade over time in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a really strange issue.  In iOS8, ONLY on the ipad 2 (works in iOS7 on all devices and the mini in iOS8), a signature panel I have will cause lines/drawn objects to fade away the longer the user holds their finger on the UIImageView.

Googling comes up with nothing, any ideas?  Here is the code for the drawing of the users taps.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
swiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
currentPoint.y -= 20;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[_drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
_drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

}
```

Comment: did u tried using CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); as a variable .. and use context in place of UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext().. ?

Comment: interesting... yeah let me try that

Comment: i tried testing your code in iOS8  its working fine :/ .

Comment: Are you using an iPad 2?  Simulator ipad 2 and ipad mini device all work fine.  but the ipad 2 device itself causes the issue.

Comment: yes i did tried using `Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)` and `iPad 2 with iOS 8.0.2` . did you tried Using `UIBezierPath` instead .

Comment: I have tied UIBezierPath yet.  I still need to test this new change.

Comment: @rahul_send89 Changing the context to a variable threw errors and wouldn't draw any lines

Comment: Hi JMD, have you resolved this issue? I have the same issue as yours... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue, and just discovered the cause.

My UIImageView was inside a UITableViewCell, and the autoresizing mask of the UIImageView was set to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth.

It turns out that removing UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight, and instead setting an explicit height for the UIImageView, resolved the problem.

I suspect this is down to the different behaviour of table cells in iOS8, as I know there is now an auto resize feature (which I haven't used yet as I had my own implementation). I suspect this is playing havoc with the flexible height resize mask, causing the distortion.